# OpenCV based programs optimization embedded linux OS

Tags: embedded, c, c++, buildroot, opencv

I'm building my own Embedded Linux OS for Raspberry PI3 using Buildroot. This OS will be used to handle several applications, one of them performs objects detection based on OpenCV (v3.3.0).

I started with Raspbian Jessy + Python but it turned out that it takes a lot of time to execute a simple example, So I decided to design my own RTOS with Optimized features + C++ development instead of Python.

I thought that with these optimizations the 4 cores of RPI + the 1GB RAM will handle such applications. The problem is that even with these things, the simplest Computer Vision programs take a lot of time.

### PC vs. Raspberry PI3 Comparaison

This is a simple program I wrote to have an idea of the order of magnitude of execution time of each part of the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"

#include <time.h>       /* clock_t, clock, CLOCKS_PER_SEC */

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setUseOptimized(true);
    clock_t t_access, t_proc, t_save, t_total;

    // Access time.
    t_access = clock();
    Mat img0 = imread("img0.jpg", IMREAD_COLOR);// takes ~90ms
    t_access = clock() - t_access;

    // Processing time
    t_proc = clock();
    cvtColor(img0, img0, CV_BGR2GRAY); 
    blur(img0, img0, Size(9,9));// takes ~18ms
    t_proc = clock() - t_proc;

    // Saving time
    t_save = clock();
    imwrite("img1.jpg", img0);
    t_save = clock() - t_save;

    t_total = t_access + t_proc + t_save;

    //printf("CLOCKS_PER_SEC = %d\n\n", CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    printf("(TEST 0) Total execution time\t %d cycles \t= %f ms!\n", t_total,((float)t_total)*1000./CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    printf("---->> Accessing  in\t %d cycles \t= %f ms.\n", t_access,((float)t_access)*1000./CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    printf("---->> Processing in\t %d cycles \t= %f ms.\n", t_proc,((float)t_proc)*1000./CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    printf("---->> Saving     in\t %d cycles \t= %f ms.\n", t_save,((float)t_save)*1000./CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    return 0;
}
```

**Results of Execution on an i7 PC**
[image]

**Results of Execution on Raspberry PI (Generated OS from Buildroot)**
[image]

As you can see there is a huge difference. What I need is to optimize every single detail so that this example **processing** step occurs in "near" real-time at **in a maximum 15ms time**.

My question is about:

- How can I optimize my OS so that it can handle intensive calculations applications and how can control the priorities of each part?
- How can I fully use the 4 Cores of RPI3 to fulfill the requirements?
- Is there any other possibilities instead of OpenCV?
- Should I use C instead of C++?
- Any hardware improvements you recommend?

Comment: Screenshots are not very welcomed here, if you can, use copy-paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order:

> How can I optimize my OS so that it can handle intensive calculations applications and how can control the priorities of each part?

For general optimization, there's not much you can do on the OS side beyond the normal stuff like making sure you have only what you actually need running in the background.  On the original Pi, you could speed up `memmove()` and similar functions by `LD_PRELOAD`'ing a library called 'cofi' that provided assembly optimized versions of those functions, but I'm not sure if it will help on a Pi 3.

For prioritization, that's really something to look at man pages for, but you generally can't do it unless you parallelize things (in your case, it seems like the obvious solution is to run each step as it's won process and use IPC (probably shared memory for performance reasons) to move the data between them).

On the note of the results you quoted from your test program, notice in particular that the processing and saving steps are both about 10 times slower on the Pi, while the access step is only about 5 times slower, and those numbers match up with a rough estimate of what I would expect when comparing a Pi 3 to a generic PC that's less than a year old.  The CPU in the Pi is almost certainly significantly slower than what you ran the PC test on (and if you didn't parallelize things at all, then the gap widens even more, as most modern x86 CPU's can run a single core by itself at full load much faster than they can run all their cores at full load), and that will have an impact.  The ARM ISA is also significantly different from the x86 ISA (ARM tends to do less per-cycle compared to x86, but doesn't usually need to access RAM as often and usually doesn't make branch prediction misses as expensive as x86 does), so any code that's optimized for how GCC arranges things on a PC is not going to be as optimal on a Pi.

I don't know about what camera you're using either, but I would expect that you could get better times by cutting the resolution of the images you're processing, and you can probably cut down on the acquisition time if you avoid using compressed formats (and not using lossy compression means that the resolution won't matter as much).

> How can I fully use the 4 Cores of RPI3 to fulfill the requirements?

Parallelization in your own code.  You just need to make sure SMP is enabled in your kernel (and if you're using the official config from the RPi Foundation, it should be), and then try to run things in parallel.  I'm not certain how much OpenCV does to parallelize things itself, but you may want to look at OpenMP as well (it provides a reasonably easy way to parallelize iterations in loops that aren't interdependent).

> Is there any other possibilities instead of OpenCV?

There might be, but everyone's standardized on OpenCV, so I would suggest using that (you'll have an easier time getting technical help with implementing things because everyone uses it).

> Should I use C instead of C++?

That depends on how you're using things.  While it's a lot easier to write slow code in C++ than C, it's no more difficult to write fast code in either language.  A lot of the optimization techniques are pretty similar in both languages (for example, pre-allocating everything at startup so you aren't calling `malloc()` in critical sections, or avoiding calling `stat()`).  In the case of C++ specifically though, avoid `std::string` like the plague, it calls `malloc()` all over the place, and as a result is insanely slow (I've seen conversions that switch from `std::string` to C-style strings improve performance by over 40% in some cases).

> Any hardware improvements you recommend?

Under the assumption that you're trying to keep hardware costs low and are space constrained (thus the choice of the Raspberry Pi), there aren't really any I can think of.  The Pi (in all of it's iterations) uses a SoC that's pretty uniquely suited for computer vision work at that price range.  If you are willing to go with something a bit bigger, and somewhat more expensive, I might suggest an NVIDIA Jetson board (they use a Tegra SoC that's got a Quadro-equivalent GPU integrated with 192 CUDA cores, so it could probably run your processing workload much faster), but getting Buildroot working on there is significantly more involved than on a Pi.

**Edits in response to comments:**

Parallelization at a process level isn't the same thing as multithreading, it's drastically different (the biggest difference is in how resources get shared, by default threads share everything, process share nothing).  In general, when there's lots of processing involved, you're (usually) better off using process-based parallelization, as it's easier to write efficient code without having to worry about thread safety.

As far as options, the two you mentioned can have a big impact on system performance, but they both end up being trade-offs between throughput and latency.  The preemption model controls how things running in kernel mode (like syscalls) can be rescheduled.  The three options there are:

1. No Preemption:  This pretty much means that anything running in kernel mode can't be interrupted.  It matches how SVR4 and 4.4BSD behaved, as well as how most other older UNIX systems work.  It's very good for throughput, but very bad for latency, so it's generally only used on big servers with lots of CPU's (more CPU's means it's more likely that one will be running something that can be preempted).
2. Voluntary Preemption:  This lets each function in the kernel define locations that it can be rescheduled.  This is the setting that most desktop targeted Linux distributions use, as it gives a good balance between throughput and latency.
3. Full Preemption: This means that (almost) any code in the kernel can be interrupted at (almost) any time.  This is useful for systems which need very low latency with respect to input and external events, such as systems used for real-time multimedia work.  It's absolutely horrible for throughput, but you can't beat the latency.

The timer frequency in contrast is much easier to explain.  It controls the longest period of time that something can run uninterrupted if there is something else waiting to run.  Higher values result in a shorter period of time (lower latency, and lower throughput), lower values a longer period (higher latency, and higher throughput).  For a general start, I'd suggest setting the preemption model to voluntary, and the timer frequency to 300 Hz, and then start experimenting with changing the timer frequency first (as that will usually have a more visible impact).

As for the Movidius NCS, whether or not it's worth it depends on how much data you need to work with because it will be bandwidth constrained by the USB connection (the Pi only has a single USB 2.0 controller, so not only are you limited to less than a tenth of the bandwidth the Movidius is designed for, you also have to share the bus with at least the Ethernet adapter, which will hurt both your latency and your throughput).  If you're only doing single frames of 1920x1080 with 32-bit color at a low rate, then it might be viable, but if you need to do streaming processing of that same video at full frame rates, then you will probably run into latency issues.  If you do choose to use one, make sure you get a powered hub for it (otherwise you may have issues with it trying to draw more power than the Pi can provide).

Comment: Thank you very much for the very detailed feedback. I've read your answer and came back with some additional questions:
- You said that i can parallelize by putting each step in a single process and communicate between them .. is this the same as using Multhreading between the operations? is there any difference? (I'm not too familiar with multithreading in c++)
- SMP is already activated. I saw some additional parameters in the buildroot configuration "Preemption Model" and "Timer Frequency" are these influencing?
- I thought about Movidius NCS, not sure if it's worth?

Comment: @NoureddineAitSaid I've updated my answer with a response to your comment, since it would have been too long for a comment.

Comment: Okay @Austin Hemmelgarn Thank you very very much for the very detailed answer.